# Msgbox if YES or NO

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

This should be super easy! The code merely consists of a message box with a Yes or No choice. Given that choice, a corresponding string is written into cell A1. I see no problem with it compared to google's script examples. What am I missing?

```
function msgbox() {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var s = ss.getActiveSheet();

var answer = Browser.msgBox("Confirm", "Does this work?", Browser.Buttons.YES_NO);

//if user clicks yes
if(answer === Browser.Buttons.YES) {
    //then enter YES into cell A1
    s.getRange("A1").setValue() === "YES";
    } else {
    //else enter NO into cell A1
    s.getRange("A1").setValue() === "NO";
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never used Google App Scripts, but based on my other programming experiences, I feel like

```
s.getRange("A1").setValue() === "YES";
```

might be the problem. Usually, the '===' operator is used to compare 2 values.

```
'aaa' === 'aaa' --> return true
```

In your case, don't you want to set a value?

```
s.getRange("A1").setValue("YES");
```

is what I would feel appropriate.

Comment: Exactly! Total brain fart. I think you, sir, should consider giving Google App Scripts a try :)

Answer (score 0):

You are simply using `setValue()` the wrong way.
Refer to the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValue(Object)).
It should simply be `s.getRange("A1").setValue('YES'`)